# What packages should I install with Cygwin to make it not bloated but also have everything I would need as a developer?

Tags: cygwin

Normally, I run Linux in a VM, however, most of my VMs are on an external HDD and I might or might not have one with me. I figure Cygwin would be a good alternative for lightweight functionality when I need something Linux like and don't have a VM on my laptop. But I'm having trouble getting the configuration right - I want the bare minimum for development + X11. Has anyone used Cygwin in this manner? If so, what suggestions do you have?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First option: don't worry about "bloat" - install everything that comes to mind.

With a permanently-available internet connection, I've also taken a "just in time" approach - the Cygwin installer makes it easy to download and install whatever you need, as and when you discover you need it.

Comment: Remember that _"install everything that comes to mind"_ doesn't mean _"install every package from Cygwin"_. 
Full installation weighs around 80GiB~ [\[1\]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21233990/2351523) in contrast eg. my _"bloated"_ cygwin dev about 7GiB.

Answer (score 31):

*Update: I've switched over to [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl) since posting this answer. If you're still using Cygwin give it a try. It's not a drop-in replacement but it's nicer in a number of ways.*

Personally, I find having to exit Cygwin just to install new packages annoying enough to try to avoid the just-in-time strategy, and fortunately there's a tool to make this much easier: [`apt-cyg`](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg).  This way you actually can just-in-time install packages without having to quit Cygwin.

That said, here's a list of common packages you might want to install, whether via the installer or via `apt-cyg`:

- `bash-completion`
- `lynx` (to install `apt-cyg`), `wget` and `curl`
- `vim`
- `hg`, `git`, and maybe `svn` and `git-svn`
- `diffutils` and `patchutils`
- `python` and `python3`

There's tons of Cygwin setup posts out on the internet too, I referenced [this one](http://guysherman.com/2013/11/02/my-ultimate-cygwin-setup/).

Comment: `rxvt-unicode` for a better console.

Answer (score 9):

The only way here is trial-and-error. Start with an absolute minimal installation and add things as you find that you need them.