# Open Cygwin at a specific folder

Tags: windows, cygwin

How can I create a Cygwin shortcut that will open Cygwin at a specific folder? This would obviate having to type

```
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/Tom/Desktop/
```

each time I launch Cygwin.

Comment: create a .bat file: here is a tutorial http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm

Comment: Note: The chere package may need to be instantiated with administrator privileges. If you are caught by this, and are tempted to use `sudo`, you may not get the expected result. In this case, login as an admin user on the windows machine.

Answer (score 451, accepted):

When you install Cygwin (or if you’ve already installed it, download it again and start setup again to run an update), make sure that you select the `chere` package under the "Shells" category.

After Cygwin is launched, open up a Cygwin terminal (as an administrator) and type the command: `chere -i -t mintty -s bash`.

Now you should have "Bash Prompt Here" in the Windows right-click context menu.

([mintty](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/) is Cygwin's default terminal. If you don't choose it with the `-t` option, your "Bash Prompt Here" will use the same terminal as the Windows Command Prompt, which prevents horizontal resizing.)

Comment: Awesome find, thanks!  I discovered that you can specify the terminal you want to open using `-t`, e.g., to open mintty you use `chere -i -t mintty`

Comment: I don't see any chere package :/ UPDATE: not in the x64 version, but it is present in the 32bit one.

Comment: @zupa did you managed to install chere in your x64 version? Or do you have to install the 32 bit version? Cheers

Comment: @pandita not in the x64 version, and I didn't bother to reinstall. Went with paxdiablo's aliasing solution

Comment: Just tested with 64bit cygwin (1.7.27) and chere seems to now exist.
pro-tip: remember to launch cygwin terminal with admin privileges.

Comment: One more thing to note. If you already did this with `chere -i -t mintty -f` to force the overwrite. You will still need to run cygwin as an administrator as well.

Comment: here's a nice how-to on this with pictures: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/16/open-cygwin-bash-shell-here/

Comment: Had permission issues on W7x64 (Error (5): Access is denied. Hive not writable). Resolved by launching Cygwin as administrator.

Comment: `chere`s for this answer :)
Confirming working on x64.

Comment: Excellent! `chere -i -t mintty -s zsh` got me the option: "open zsh prompt here". Just the ticket!

Comment: This whole suggestion is a big waste of time based on the original question. It emulates linux....so use bashrc. @bschwagg has the answer below.

Comment: I don't understand... ok, so I have to run as *administrator" once for it to set things up, but then something is supposed to show up under a right click WHERE?  I'm starting the app from the dock, which doesn't have all these right click options.

Comment: Cygwin had no default shell in my case, so adding `-s bash` to make `chere -i -t mintty -s bash` made this work for me

Comment: Had to use the `-s bash` option too, thanks for the hint!

Comment: x64 has *bash* as default shell, but the the context text is the dumb `Bash Prompt Here`, so you may consider using `chere -i -t mintty -e "Open Cygwin Here"` instead.

Comment: Heads up if you run `tmux`: you have to exit it before trying `chere -i -t mintty`, otherwise you'll run into the admin privilege issues.

Comment: Tip: if you [install `apt-cyg`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29291849/113632) when you first set up Cygwin, you don't have to re-run the setup wizard in order to install additional packages. I just ran `apt-cyg install chere` and I was up and running.

Comment: In latest versions you also need to specify shell via `-s bash` (or any other shell you need).

Comment: Hm, my Cygwin installer doesn't have chere listed anywhere in the packages, only bash, dash, and mintty (and chere isn't recognize with all three of these installed.) I'm using setup-x86_64.exe from this week.

Comment: If anybody wants to remove the context menu entry, simply swap the -i (install) argument for -u (uninstall), e.g: `chere -u -t mintty -s bash`

Comment: Nowadays chere has a -c option to install it just for the current user, no admin privileges required. It still prints an access denied error because it cannot register the uninstaller with Windows. There is another flag -m to avoid that as well. Using -p you can see what it would do to the registry.

Answer (score 113):

Here's what I use. It doesn't require `chere` package or registry tinkering.  Works on Windows 7.

Go to your "Send To" folder:

```
C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

Create a shortcut named `Bash Here` having this in the `Target` field:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico  C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe  -l -c "cd \"$0\" ; exec bash"
```

In the Windows Explorer, you right-click on a folder & select `Send To > Bash Here`.

And here's the opposite trick, opening a Windows Explorer in your current bash dir.  Create this alias:

```
alias winx='/cygdrive/c/Windows/explorer.exe /e,\`cygpath -w .\`'
```

Note: the `cygpath -w .` part above is enclosed in back-ticks.

Now just type `winx` at the bash prompt, and a Win Explorer pops up there.

Note: If winx directs you to your documents folder, try

```
alias winx='/cygdrive/c/Windows/explorer.exe /e,`cygpath -w $PWD`'
```

Comment: Very nice trick, but the `winx` alias didn't work on my Cygwin setup. I had to remove both backslashes and replace `.` with `$PWD` for it to work.

Comment: What if the shortcut (adapted to use the Cygwin64 path of my install) opens cygwin to my user folder? :(

Maybe this only works with 32-bit Cygwin?

Comment: This one is also working for me `alias winx='/cygdrive/c/Windows/explorer.exe /e,$(cygpath -wa .)'`

Comment: In cygwin 2.6.0 (on Win 7 x64) it can be done much easier: `cygstart .` to open Explorer with the current folder, or any folder syntax `cygstart ..`, `cygstart /your/path` etc...

Comment: Warning: `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico  C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe  -l -c "cd \"$0\" ; exec bash` keeps file handle open to `$0` directory, even after you change working directory to something else. What's worse spawning copy of the window (`ALT+F2`), even when you already have changed working directory, opens another file handle to `$0`. This may interfere with some operations that may want to delete/modify `$0` in any process. If you get 'Permission Denied' error when accessing `$0` this might be the cause

Answer (score 34):

I made a .reg file that puts an "Open Cygwin Here" option in the right-click context menu.
It depends on the Cygwin "chere" package, which you can install using [apt-cyg](http://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/) if you didn't install it in the initial setup.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin_bash]
@="Open Cygwin Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin_bash\command]
@="C:\\cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe -e /bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe"
```

Comment: For those who are wondering how to use this, just copy the gray-background text and put it in a text file called "foo.reg" and double click it.

Comment: +1 the best solution here. And thanks for mentioning `apt-cyg`, I didn't know about this tool

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, and it even helped me with other things because even the Microsoft site didn't get me the same result.

Comment: I had to change to "cygwin" but I get this error: "Failed to run /bin/xhere: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Totty.js are you sure you've installed the 'chere' package in Cygwin?

Answer (score 33):

From the cygwin terminal, run this command:

`echo "cd your_path" >> ~/.bashrc`

The .bashrc script is run when you open a new bash session.  The code above with change to the **your_path** directory when you open a new cygwin session.

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER! SO EASY.

Comment: Yes ! That is easy ! Vote up !

Comment: This is not the answer, because it doesn't create a shortcut that uses said directory, as required by the question, it changes the behavior of all methods of starting the Cygwin shell.  You shouldn't change a global setting (or login profile) to solve a local problem.

Comment: I once used *exactly* this method to append a user to the password file, accidentally leaving off one of the `>` characters. Then I logged out :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo  ouch

Answer (score 20):

For cygwin64 or installations without chere you can use the following command in a registry entry (assuming windows due to your path, also assuming cygwin installation directory is c:\cygwin64)

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/sh -lc 'cd "`cygpath "%V"`"; bash'
```

Works on Windows 7 and 8
Registry file available for download here: http://tomkay.me/blog/Cygwin64---Open-Here-18

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Open cygwin to folder
; http://tomkay.me - Tom Kay

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open_cygwin]
@="Open Cygwin Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open_cygwin\command]
@="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe /bin/sh -lc 'cd \"`cygpath \"%V\"`\"; bash'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\open_cygwin]
@="Open Cygwin Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\open_cygwin\command]
@="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe /bin/sh -lc 'cd \"`cygpath \"%V\"`\"; bash'"
```

Comment: Can you explain why you have 3 (x2) registry entries?

Comment: they are for Directory, Drive and Background contexts

Comment: Finally, one solution which worked for me, although I have some issues understanding it completely ;-) [the 'bash' after 'exec bash']. Hint: you can replace the 3 entries with 1: 'Folder' instead of 'Directory', 'Drive' and 'Background'.

Comment: with just 'Folder', the link appears in the context menu of a drive, but fails to execute.  However, I have been able to cut down to 2 entries with 'Folder' and 'Directory\Background'

Comment: For emacs:
"C:\\cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico /bin/bash -l -c 'emacs \"`cygpath \"%V\"`\";'"

Comment: Thanks for stating the simple `mintty` incantation with the right amount of escaping. This made it easier to adapt your solution to my FreeCommander setup.

Comment: This ``/bin/sh -lc 'cd \"`cygpath \"%V\"`\"; bash'`` will cause `mintty` to always ask **`Processes are running in session ... Close anyway?`** when closing the `mintty` terminal by hitting the window X close button.

Comment: @user The last command replaces `bash` with `exec bash` to avoid a confirmation prompt when closing.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to have that directory as your default, simply add a `cd` statement to your `~/.profile` file.

What I tend to do is use that method to set my usual directory, plus define aliases for my common cases as well:

```
alias tom="cd /users/tom"
```

or your equivalent. This lets me change directories very fast.

Comment: Does that alias have to be added to the `~/.profile` file, too, or just run once?

Comment: @tomeoftom, if you just run that within a shell, it will only affect that shell. It won't affect any others you start. So, if you want it to be always available, you need to put it in one of your startup files (of which `~/.profile` is one possibility).

Comment: it didn't work for me when put in ~/.profile, but ~/.bashrc worked.

Comment: @zupa, the rules as to which startup files are sourced are reasonably complicated (though it's all there in the `bash` man page if you dig deep enough). That's why I stated `.profile` as one possibility.

Comment: .profile ultimately sources .bashrc so you might want to append that command into bashrc instead. (.profile didn't work for me)

Comment: Just one nitpick, @laertis: whether or not `.profile` sources `.bashrc` depends *entirely* on the contents of `.profile`. It may or it may not, depending on how you've set things up.

Answer (score 10):

As two7s_clash said you first need to install `chere` package and setup mintty:

1. Open Cygwin terminal as administrator
2. `apt-cyg install chere`
3. `chere -i -t mintty`

You are now able to open cygwin in specific directory with a Right mouse click in Windows Explorer (Context Menu) and select "Bash Prompt Here".

You can also open cygwin from a specific directory using windows command prompt:

1. Open windows command prompt
2. Navigate (`cd`) to custom directory
3. Execute `C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe C:\cygwin64\bin\env.exe CHERE_INVOKING=1 C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l`

   This command will open cygwin with current directory taken from command prompt.

#### FreeCommander

This command can also be used to open cygwin from custom file manager, like FreeCommander.

To open cygwin with current directory taken from FreeCommander, do the following:

1. Tools -> Favorite Tools -> Favorite tools edit... (Ctrl + Shift + Y)
2. Add a new toolbar (+ Icon), Shortcut: Insert

   - Name: cygwin
   - Program or folder: `C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe`
   - Start folder: `%ActivDir%`
   - Parameter: `C:\cygwin64\bin\env.exe CHERE_INVOKING=1 C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l`

You can add custom shortcut to open cygwin from FreeCommander:

1. Tools -> Define keyboard shortcuts
2. Scroll down to "Favorite tool 01" (or "Favorite tool N")
3. Assign new shortcut key: I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Great reference: [MinTTY Wiki, article Tips: Starting in a particular directory](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/Tips#starting_in_a_particular_directory)

Answer (score 8):

I use and Icon to launch my cygwin without the `chere` package.

1. Create a shortcut on my desktop for the cygwin terminal.
2. R-click the icon and select properties.
3. On the shortcut tab, use this for the TARGET:
   `C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -c 'cd'`
4. For START IN, Put the path of the dir/folder where you want to
   launch cygwin.  i.e. `C:\some\dir\name\here`

Comment: ok 2 things   

1. appending `-c` in "Target" makes no difference as long you provide a path in "Start In"   

2. this solution creates an issue with `PATH`. cygwin fails to prepend `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin` in the system PATH leaving unable to invoke some of its binaries   

The configuration probably reside in `/etc/profile` >> ` if [ ${CYGWIN_NOWINPATH-addwinpath} = "addwinpath" ] ; then
`

Answer (score 6):

To create a Windows shortcut that launches a Cygwin terminal in a directory of your own choosing, try the following:

- Right-click on the Windows desktop, select 'New', and then select 'Shortcut'.
- For location of the item, enter the following text, changing the `mintty` path as needed and substituting the name of the desired directory where indicated.

  ```
  C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/sh -lc 'cd DESIRED-DIRECTORY; exec bash'
  ```

  For example, the OP would use the following text:

  ```
  C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/sh -lc 'cd /cygdrive/c/Users/Tom/Desktop/; exec bash'
  ```
- Click 'Next'.
- Enter the desired name for the shortcut and click 'Finish'.

Multiple shortcuts can be placed on the desktop to open Cygwin terminals in various often-accessed directories.

Inspired by solution posted on [How to open a Cygwin shell at a specific directory from Netbeans?](https://superuser.com/questions/592086/how-to-open-a-cygwin-shell-at-a-specific-directory-from-netbeans) at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 4):

Find file Cygwin.bat and make content like this:

```
@echo off
set newpath=%cd:\=/%
pushd "%~dp0"
chdir bin
bash --login -i -c "cd \"%newpath%\"; exec bash"
```

Add path to cygwin.bat to environment PATH.

Now in any folder you can type to address bar:

```
cygwin
```

Also you can type it when you in cmd.exe

Answer (score 3):

I have made a registry edit script to open Cygwin at any folder you right click. It's on my GitHub.

[Here's my GitHub](http://github.com/umer936/CygwinHere)

**Sample `RegEdit` code from Github for 64-bit machines:**

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CygwinHere]
@="&Cygwin Bash Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CygwinHere\command]
@="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c \"cd \\\"%V\\\" ; exec bash -rcfile ~/.bashrc\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\CygwinHere]
@="&Cygwin Bash Here"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\CygwinHere\command]
@="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c \"cd \\\"%V\\\" ; exec bash -rcfile ~/.bashrc\""
```

Comment: If you get "Error accessing the registry." error see answer by @mpersico below... would have saved me 15 minutes :)

Answer (score 3):

I used the following lines of code to start zsh in the current directory in Win7.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin_bash]
@="Open Cygwin Here"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin_bash\command]
@="\"C:\\Programmieren\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe\" -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico /bin/zsh --login -c 'cd \"%V\";zsh'"
```

note that i used %V instead of %L or %1 (since both didn't work for me)

Answer (score 3):

When a fresh install is needed, I create a Windows "user environment variable " named `HOME` and assigns it the path of wherever "My Documents" reside.

The cygwin installer detects the `HOME` variable, automatically translates this into a cygpath and selects this it to be my ~ directory.

This has worked fine for every workstation I have used professionally the last 5 years (about 3 or 4, Win7). I have always been the only user on these machines, cannot say what the effect is.

Answer (score 3):

Save the following code as a file: `cygwin_bash.reg`

This will add opening Cygwin in the current directory and opening Cygwin in the specified folder at the same time.

Use "`.bashrc`" instead of "`.bash_profile`" configuration. Because of `exec bash`. `.bashrc` is executed for interactive non-login shells. see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\z_cygwin_bash]
@="Cygwin Here"
"Icon"="C:\\cygwin64\\Cygwin.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\z_cygwin_bash\command]
@="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe /bin/sh -lc 'cd \"`cygpath \"%V\"`\"; exec bash'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\z_cygwin_bash]
@="Cygwin Here"
"Icon"="C:\\cygwin64\\Cygwin.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\z_cygwin_bash\command]
@="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe /bin/sh -lc 'cd \"`cygpath \"%V\"`\"; exec bash'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Open Cygwin terminal as Administrator

In powershell (using chocolatey):

```
choco install cyg-get
```

In cygwin
Will Install right-click menu

```
cyg-get install chere
chere -i
```

Now you can right click and use "Bash Prompt Here" in any folder.

Answer (score 1):

In the answer that uses the registry, I found that on Windows 2008 R2 SP1, you need to drop the Background out of the path. Further, since the chere and xhere are not part of cygwin64, here is a solution that works for both, combining the registry and the Send To solutions. Replace 'E:\cygwin64' with your install location:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cygwin_bash]
@="Open Cygwin Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cygwin_bash\command]
@="E:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico --exec /bin/bash.exe --login -c \"cd '%1' ; exec bash -rcfile ~/.bashrc\""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the icon to the shell by adding an `Icon` field set to the path to your `Cygwin.ico` file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin_bash]
@="Cygwin"
"Icon"="\"C:\\cygwin64\\Cygwin.ico\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin_bash\command]
@="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe -e /bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe"
```

Comment: I think a prerequisite to xhere's existence is the installation of chere, as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows machine it was not taking:

chere -i -t mintty

Because mintty shell was not available,but you might have choice of various other shells like ash bash cmd dash mksh pdksh posh tcsh zsh passwd.

so I used :

chere -i -s bash

Comment: Mintty is not a shell, it is a terminal emulator.

Comment: How does this answer the original question?

Comment: This will provide the help to those who do not have mintty in their system and get error when trying to attempt the solution provided above, I also followed the solution provided above but it didnt work on my windows machine, but my answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can just open cygwin terminal and write: cd and after drag n drop the folder you want end enter!

Comment: While this doesn't fully solve the question asked, it is a very useful tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only Cygwin64 registry solution that worked for me in Windows 8.1:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\mintty]
@="Mintty from Here"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\mintty\command]
@="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe -h always -e /usr/bin/ash -c 'cd  \"$(/usr/bin/cygpath \"%L\")\";  exec /usr/bin/bash  '"
```

Make sure you modify your 'C:\cygwin64' path as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the batch file and put it to the Cygwin's /bin directory. This script was developed so it allows to install/uninstall the registry entries for opening selected folders and drives in Cygwin. For details see the link http://with-love-from-siberia.blogspot.com/2013/12/cygwin-here.html.

update: This solution does the same as early suggestions but all manipulations with Windows Registry are hidden within the script.

Perform the command to install

```
cyghere.bat /install
```

Perform the command to uninstall

```
cyghere.bat /uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also problem with git, that used to "steal" my cygwin commands - so i needed to run 
  `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -` 
but after installing `chere` and executing `chere -i -t mintty -f`  as admin (see above), you can simply use : 
 `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -e /bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe "."` 
I added this in Total Commander as custom button (right click on panel > add ...)  and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash file say `move.sh` which has the following code 
`C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe -p /bin bash runFile.sh`
This starts the Cygwin and executes the `runFile.sh` present in the bin directory of Cygwin
Suppose you want to navigate to a specific directory say `E:\code`
then runFile.sh has the following code `cd E:
cd code`

Answer (score 0):

Finally an answer which is independent of Cygwin itself.

This uses the fact that, if I am on the directory `C:\\Cool` and I call the command `C:\\Cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe`, `mintty` will automatically open on the current directory, i.e., `C:\\Cool`.

First, you will need to create the file `C:\\Cygwin\\silent_run.vbs` with the following contents:

```
Function EnquoteString(argument)
  EnquoteString = Chr(34) & argument & Chr(34)
End Function

arglist = ""
With WScript.Arguments
    For Each arg In .Unnamed
        ' Wscript.Echo "Unnamed: " & arg
        If InStr(arg, " ") > 0 Then
            ' arg contains a space
            arglist = arglist & " " & EnquoteString(arg)
        Else
            arglist = arglist & " " & arg
        End If
    Next
End With

CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run Trim( arglist ), 0, False
```

Next, to install this answer, you will use a Windows Registry file. For that, just put the contents of the following file into a file named `C:\\Cygwin\\AddMinttyToContextMenu.reg`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Terminal Here]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe\""
"Position"="Middle"
@="Terminal Here"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Terminal Here\Command]
@="\"C:\\Cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe\" -w max"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Terminal Here]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe\""
"Position"="Middle"
@="Terminal Here"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Terminal Here\Command]
@="cmd.exe /c cd /d \"%V\" && wscript \"C:\\Cygwin\\silent_run.vbs\" \"C:\\Cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe\" -w max"
```

Now, Fix all hard coded paths, i.e, `C:\\Cygwin` to the actual location where your Cygwin installation is on.

Then, just open the file `C:\\Cygwin\\AddMinttyToContextMenu.reg` to install your new registry entries and you are done.

The file `C:\\Cygwin\\AddMinttyToContextMenu.reg` works by opening first a `cmd.exe`, changing to the directory where you are in, then, calling `C:\\Cygwin\\silent_run.vbs` to open the `C:\\Cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe` terminal with the command line options `-w max`, i.e., to open it maximized.

The script `C:\\Cygwin\\silent_run.vbs` is required to open the `C:\\Cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe` terminal without keeping the first `cmd.exe` we opened, open.

The first entry of `C:\\Cygwin\\AddMinttyToContextMenu.reg` does not use `C:\\Cygwin\\silent_run.vbs` because by default the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` keys are already open in the current directory, then, we can just call `C:\\Cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe` directly to get it working out of the box.

References:

1. [How add context menu item to Windows Explorer for folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders)
2. [VBScript pass commandline argument in paths with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841912/vbscript-pass-commandline-argument-in-paths-with-spaces)
3. [How to pass a command with spaces and quotes as a single parameter to CScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091711/how-to-pass-a-command-with-spaces-and-quotes-as-a-single-parameter-to-cscript)
4. [calling vbscript from another vbscript file passing arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437633/calling-vbscript-from-another-vbscript-file-passing-arguments)
5. https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-args.html
6. [Check if string contains space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370456/check-if-string-contains-space)
7. [Running command line silently with VbScript and getting output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690134/running-command-line-silently-with-vbscript-and-getting-output)
8. http://www.vbsedit.com/html/6f28899c-d653-4555-8a59-49640b0e32ea.asp
9. https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way
10. [How to run Batch script received as argument on VBscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239157/how-to-run-batch-script-received-as-argument-on-vbscript)
11. [Can I pass an argument to a VBScript (vbs file launched with cscript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806713/can-i-pass-an-argument-to-a-vbscript-vbs-file-launched-with-cscript)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11, I created this reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cygwin_shell]
@="&Bash Prompt Here"
"Icon"="C:\\local\\cygwin64\\Cygwin-Terminal.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cygwin_shell\command]
@="C:\\local\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe -e /bin/xhere /bin/bash.exe \"%L\""
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off
C:
SET mypath=%~dp0
c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "cd '%mypath%'; export CHERE_INVOKING=1; exec /bin/bash --login -i"
```

Copy above commands in a text file and save it as .bat in any of "your folder of interest".
It should open cygwin in "your folder of interest".

Answer (score -1):

based on @LindseyD answer I created a simple BAT file, that opens cygwin in current directory, it may be useful (for me it is). Assuming that You have cygwin's bin directory in PATH.

```
FOR /F %%x IN ('sh -c pwd') DO bash -l -i -c 'cd %%x; exec bash'
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why I had to wast so much time, but this works for me on win 10, 64 bit:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin_bash]
@="Open Cygwin Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cygwin_bash\command]
@="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c \"cd \\\"%V\\\" ; exec bash -rcfile ~/.bashrc\""
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably the simplest one:

1) Create file foo.reg

2) Insert content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\open_mintty]
@="open mintty"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\open_mintty\command]
@="cmd /C mintty"
```

3) Execute foo.reg

Now just right-click in any folder, click `open mintty` and it will spawn mintty in that folder.

Answer (score -2):

Best to do like below:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\BashHere
Enter Data: Bash Here

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\BashHere\command
Enter Data: 

cmd.exe /c C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -c "cd '%1'; exec /bin/bash"
```