# Unable to maximize cygwin after opening from context menu

Tags: windows, cygwin

Using the `chere` command at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637601/open-cygwin-at-a-specific-folder) I was able to add the 'open bash terminal here' to my windows shell.

However, it looks like rather than opening in a regular cygwin shell it opens in a cmd prompt that's running cygwin. I am unable to maximize cygwin fully. I can change the settings via properties for the cmd window, but then it ALWAYS opens like that, instead of in the regular smaller screen.

Is there a way to maximize the shell to its full maximum size (the whole screen)? I'll accept a command that I type in, so long as I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637601/open-cygwin-at-a-specific-folder/12010346#12010346) I was able to specify `mintty` as the shell that opened with

```
chere -i -f -t mintty
```

(the `-f` overrides the previous chere command, the `-t mintty` specifies which terminal to open)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [mintty](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Mintty). This code can do
that. Save as `cygwin.reg` and run.

```r
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Cygwin\command]
@="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty"
```

Comment: I think you're right, I'll bet if I do what [the top comment on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12010346/3665278) says it'll launch mintty without having to edit the registry, too