# How to change directory in bash upon bash --login -i

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

I am using `Cygwin` and wish to run it with diff params so I can change dir as soon as I launch in Windows.

For example

```
bash --login -i ; cd /
```

or

```
bash --login -i ; cd /tmp
```

but the `cd` does not work, how can I pass a change directory to

```
bash --login -i
```

FYI I can't put the `cd` in .bash, it has to be passed in

tried this with no luck

```
bash --login -i -s cd /tmp;
```

Comment: May be other relevant answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637601/open-cygwin-at-a-specific-folder

Comment: While [this](https://superuser.com/questions/341534/how-to-start-an-interactive-shell-with-special-setup) solution is about zsh, the same strategy could be used for bash. See particularily the comment given by _Martin_ to the accepted answer of that question, or my answer to the question (which was not accepted).

Answer (score 5):

One hack is to use `-c` to change the directory, then immediately start a new shell in place of the first one. The working directory is inherited. Note that *any* shell (that supports `exec`) could be used to start the new process; once the working directory has been changed, then you can start the interactive login instance of `bash`.

```
bash -c "cd /tmp; exec bash --login -i"
```

Comment: That works for me using the 32-bit Cygwin on Windows 7 SP1 with all updates applied. @born2net, is it possible you have a `cd` command in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files?

Comment: Another approach is to use `script` utility: `script.exe -q -c "cd /tmp; CHERE_INVOKING=. /bin/bash -l"`

Answer (score 2):

ok so I found a solution to what I needed.
in Cygwin .bashrc I put

`"$OLDPWD"`
and it will automatically switch me to the last directory I was in Windows before forks Cygwin.

Comment: should be `cd "$OLDPWD"`

Comment: As long as cygwin uses `CHERE_INVOKING` variable, then it is enough to declare it in the script: `bash -c "cd '...'; CHERE_INVOKING=. exec bash -l -i"`. The `$OLDPWD` will point a previous current directory just before the `cd "..."`.

Answer (score 1):

I use `.bashrc` and `.bash_logout` to recover previous locations.  In `.bash_logout` I store the current directory in a file:

```
if [ -d ~/.recent-locations ]; then
    pwd > ~/.recent-locations/locus-$RANDOM
fi
```

and in `.bashrc` I consume the stored locations:

```
if [ -d .recent-locations ]; then
    for x in $(ls .recent-locations); do
        dstdir=$(cat .recent-locations/$x)
        rm .recent-locations/$x
        cd $dstdir
        break
    done
fi
```

For this to work you need to logout explicitly using `Ctrl-D` or `logout`; on the other hand if you don't want to record your location you simply shut down the terminal window via the window manager.