# cygwin issues with cancelling out path and finding files

Tags: linux, path, directory, cygwin

Two issues I am having trouble with:

1. I tried the following suggestion to get a path to be set as the "default" one but now I have some issues. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27070063/6148484

Everytime I open the cygwin terminal, there are these at the top and I would like to remove them. (I suppose they were from codes that I typed with error while trying to execute the link above) I would hence like to remove this effect but I do not know how to do that.

```
-bash: cd: too many arguments
```

2. I am unable to see some files/folders when I type ls. There seems to be no update in the folders/directories that I am in after I make changes to the files/folders. Perhaps it is because of the line I tried above (see question 1)?

Comment: may be if you tell us what you have in `.bashrc` we will have a clue.

Comment: Hello @Raycherr - If you run the command `cat ~/.bashrc` it will display the contents of the file in question.  Put the result in your question here, as it will provide some needed context.  Thanks.

Comment: There are several suggestions in the referenced SO topic. Please indicate which one you are using. Also show us the messages that appear at the top of your terminal. Note that the `chere` solution is the recomended one, as it is supported by the cygwin maintainers. Also installation using the setup exe downloaded from the cygwin home page is the recommended install method and should be used to eliminate the possibility of problems due to alternate install methods.